# Flask mail does not send mail when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, email, flask

I am writing a little web application based on Miguel Grinberg's [Flasky](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky). I use the exact same code for user confirmation emails. When DEBUG=True (for Flask), everything works like a charm. When DEBUG=False, however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
 self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "/home/fabee/code/rowbot/app/email.py", line 9, in send_async_email
    mail.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 491, in send
    with self.connect() as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 144, in __enter__
self.host = self.configure_host()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask_mail.py", line 163, in configure_host
host.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 671, in starttls
self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 569, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 423, in ehlo
self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 349, in putcmd
self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 341, in send
raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

I find this really hard to debug because I do not really understand what DEBUG=True really implies. Any hints and help on that is greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Code**

This is the file with the email methods:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import current_app, render_template
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from . import mail


def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(app.config['MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject,
                  sender=app.config['MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)

    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr
```

This is the code where `mail` gets created:

```
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
mail = Mail()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()
pagedown = PageDown()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    QRcode(app)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    pagedown.init_app(app)

    if not app.debug and not app.testing and not app.config['SSL_DISABLE']:
        from flask.ext.sslify import SSLify
        sslify = SSLify(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')


    ...

    return app
```

This is where the email is sent:

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(email=form.email.data,
                    username=form.username.data,
                    password=form.password.data,
                    name=form.realname.data,
                    role_id=Role.query.filter_by(name='User').first().id)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        confirm_token = user.generate_token()
        reject_token = user.generate_token(action='reject')
        for admin in User.admins():
            send_email(admin.email, 'Please Confirm Row-Bot Account for User {0} ({1})'.format(user.username, user.name),
                   'auth/email/register', user=user, confirm_token=confirm_token, reject_token=reject_token)
        flash('A request email has been sent to our admins.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('auth/register.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Please write the code that you are using. It is hard to guess where you are wrong without the code.

Comment: There it is. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: What about the configurations ? Server, Port etc.

Comment: Nothing special. Email uses TLS on port 587. The really weird thing is that the *only* difference between working and not working is `DEBUG=True`.

Comment: Hey, Were you able to resolve the error?

Comment: Nope, your example works, but I still have the same bug. I can't find what's different.

Comment: Alright, found the error: I imported environmental variables from a file. In DEBUG mode that file was somehow read correctly, but in production mode the file was read to late. I'll upvote your answer because it helped finding the bug, but I am not accepting it because it is not the answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't figure out where you went wrong but can you try to match this

```
from flask import Flask, current_app

from flask_mail import Mail, Message

import threading
#mail = Mail()
app = Flask(__name__)

#DEBUG = True


app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']= 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL']= False
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'EMAIL_ID'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'PASSWORD'

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/')
def send_mail():
    send_email('EMAIL_TO')
    return "Sent"


def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)
        print "sent"

def send_email(to):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(subject='hello',
                  sender='SENDER', recipients=[to])
    thr = threading.Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr

#def send_email()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Please comment below if there is still problem.

And `DEBUG = True` means that the app is running in debug mode , and if there is any error the complete stack trace will be printed. If you don't run in debug mode then it will simply give an error like `Internal Server error` or something else.